# Qt 5.11 can't save config value to .ini file by QSettings

Tags: qt, ini, qsettings

I have a config.ini in my project.The content is

```
[Info]
username = "admin"
```

I wanna to change "/Info/username" like this:

```
QSettings *config = new QSettings(":/config/config.ini", QSettings::IniFromat);
QString username = "myname";
config->setValue("/Info/username", username);
```

Then I qDebug the value of username

```
qDebug() << config.value("/Info/username").toString();
```

It will be ok, the value of username in control is "myname",but when I check config.ini, I find it still is "username".That means the change of value isn't save to config.ini permanently.

How can I save my changes of value to config.ini permanently?

Comment: The `:/` prefix on a path signifies a bound resource in `Qt` -- it's read-only and doesn't refer to an entry in the file system.  Try specifying the actual path of the config file.

Comment: call: config->sync(); after set new values.

Comment: Where is your config.ini located?